# problema al pasar datos de una clase a otra en php

Tags: php

Hola buen día tengo un problema al mostrar en una tabla html los registros traídos de una tabla en mysql. La conexión esta bien porque si registra.

Tengo esta función que esta en la clase Conexion.php la cual va a ejecutar las sentencias select.

```
public function getQuery($sentencia){
    $this->abrirConexion();

    $resultado = $this->conection->query($sentencia);

    while ( $this->datos[] = $resultado->fetch_assoc() );

    $this->cerrarConexion();

    return array_pop($this->datos);
}
```

Llamo desde otra clase ModelUser.php donde tengo las funciones crud a getQuery()

```
public function read(){
    $sql = "select * from usuario";

    $datos = array();

    $datos = $this->conection->getQuery($sql);

    return $datos;
}
```

Y en home.php que es donde se van a mostrar los registros tengo esto.

```
<?php
require('Model/ModelUser.php');
$model = new ModelUser();
 $datos = $model->read();

?>

<a href="register.html"><label>Registrar Usuario</label></a>

<?php
 if(empty($datos)){
?>
 <h2>No hay datos registrados</h2>
<?php
 }
else{
 ?>
<table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Codigo</td>
        <td>Alias</td>
        <td>Nombres</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    for ($i=0;$i<count($datos);$i++) { 
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['alias'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['nombres'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['email'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Al final aparece que no hay datos registrados.

Comment: Prueba la función así:`public function getQuery($sentencia){
    $this->abrirConexion();
    $resultado = $this->conection->query($sentencia);
    while ( $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
     $this->datos[]=$row;
 }     
    $this->cerrarConexion();
    return $this->datos;
}` y el método `read` así: `public function read(){
    $sql = "select * from usuario";
    $datos = $this->conection->getQuery($sql);
    return $datos;
}` OJO, a tu código le faltan controles, como por ejemplo si no encuentra datos, si la conexión es nula, si la SQL es errónea, etc.

Comment: Supongo que en la clase tienes declarado un miembro `private $datos = array();` Para el for, puedes leerlo así: `foreach ($datos as $row) { 
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>`  o sea, usar la notación: `$row['nombreColumna']`

Comment: Gracias a todos por responder estuve toda la tarde batallando en que se muestren los datos y no podía pero lo pude hacer con la sugerencia de @A.Cedano no se como marcarla como respuesta pero esa fue la solución. También quería consultar algo porque así while ( $this->datos[] = $resultado->fetch_assoc() );  no funciona bien si me parece que el funcionamiento es igual a   while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {$this->datos[] = $row;}  . Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios motivos por los que tu código no funciona.

En `getQuery` no estás guardando bien los datos. Como lo tienes ahora, de funcionar, te estaría guardando un valor `NULL` dentro de `$this->datos[]`, por eso te ves obligado de usar `array_pop` para quitar ese valor nulo. Es algo absurdo, no sé de donde sacaste ese estilo de programación cuando las cosas de pueden hacer de una forma más limpia (recomiendo al respecto que mires los ejemplos del Manual de PHP, verás que nunca se procede de esa manera). Lo correcto es usar una variable para el `while` y dentro del cuerpo del bucle ir llenando `$this->datos[]` con esa variable.

```
public function getQuery($sentencia){
    $this->abrirConexion();
    $resultado = $this->conection->query($sentencia);
    while ( $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $this->datos[]=$row;
    }
    $this->cerrarConexion();
    return $this->datos;
}
```

Luego, en `read()`, dado que `getQuery()` devuelve un array, no necesitas declarar la variable, en la llamada misma ya tendrás el array.

```
public function read(){
    $sql = "select * from usuario";
    $datos = $this->conection->getQuery($sql);
    return $datos;
}
```

Aunque no sé realmente qué utilidad tiene tu método `read` ¿? No hace nada de particular ni de especial. En el fondo hacer esto:

```
$instancia->read();
```

Sería lo mismo que hacer esto:

```
$instancia->getQuery("SELECT * FROM usuario");
```

Y, si tiene dentro una consulta fija que es seleccionar a todos los usuarios, debería llamarse algo así como `getAllUsers()`. Yo hablo aquí de la **coherencia del código**. No deberías llamar a un método con el nombre de `read`, cuando lo que hace es obtener todos los usuarios.

Y finalmente, en el código que presenta los datos, por tu ciclo `for` y por la forma de leer los resultados con `while` antes mencionada, me hace pensar que ¿estarás aprendiendo de tutoriales algo antiguos?

Vamos a leer los datos de una forma menos complicada con un `foreach`. También podemos evitar la mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML, aunque es lícito, produce un código difícil de leer, comprender, depurar. Se puede concatenar todo en una variable, de ese modo usamos un solo bloque PHP.

```
<?php 
    require('Model/ModelUser.php');
    $model = new ModelUser();
    $datos = $model->read();
    $html="<a href=\"register.html\"><label>Registrar Usuario</label></a>";
    if(empty($datos)){
        $html.="<h2>No hay datos registrados</h2>";
    } else {
        $html.="<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Codigo</td>
                    <td>Alias</td>
                    <td>Nombres</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";
        foreach ($datos as $row) { 
            $html.="
                <tr>
                    <td>$row[\"id\"]</td>
                    <td>$row[\"alias\"]</td>
                    <td>$row[\"nombres\"]</td>
                    <td>$row[\"email\"]</td>
                </tr>";
        }
        $html.="</tbody>";
    echo $html;
?>
```

Esto no tiene mayor misterio. Simplemente se trata de:

- Concatenar todo el contenido dentro de una variable `$html` que al principio es declarada como: `$html="Primer contenido"` y en lo sucesivo usar el operador de concatenación que este: `.=`, para seguir agregando cosas: `$html.="otro contenido";`
- Cuando hay comillas `"` dentro del contenido mismo, escaparlas con `\"`
- Al final del todo hacer `echo $html;` con todo lo que concatenamos.

Eso es todo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu explicación @A. Cedano  es muy entendible si estuve viendo algunos tutoriales para comprender mejor php y aplique mvc donde ModelUser.php lo tengo en una carpeta Model, ControllerUser.php(con la función read) en una carpeta Controller y home en View; vi que se hacia de esa manera espero que sea lo correcto. Ya poco a poco ire mejorando lo que estoy haciendo para así poder aprendiendo mucho más.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con el código asi:

```
<?php
require('Model/ModelUser.php');
$model = new ModelUser();
 $datos = $model->read();

?>

<a href="register.html"><label>Registrar Usuario</label></a>

<?php
 if(empty($datos)){
 echo '<h2>No hay datos registrados</h2>';
 }
else{
echo '<table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Codigo</td>
        <td>Alias</td>
        <td>Nombres</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>';
    for ($i=0;$i<count($datos);$i++) { echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $datos[$i]["id"] . '</td>
            <td>' . $datos[$i]["alias"] . '</td>
            <td>' . $datos[$i]["nombres"] . '</td>
            <td>' . $datos[$i]["email"] . '</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>';
}
?>
```

Tu codigo en ningún momento afectaba al h2 con el mensaje de "no hay datos registrados", por lo tanto siempre saldria

```
<?php
 if(empty($datos)){
?>
 <h2>No hay datos registrados</h2> //En ningún momento es afectado por el if
<?php
 }
else{
 ?>
```

Por otro lado esta parte del código estaba bien, pero lo organice un poco mejor y además así creo que funcionaria mejor

```
<?php
 }
else{
 ?>
<table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Codigo</td>
        <td>Alias</td>
        <td>Nombres</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    for ($i=0;$i<count($datos);$i++) { 
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['alias'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['nombres'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['email'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: que modificaste? recuerda agregar explicación para que la respuesta le sea mas útil no solo a quien preguntó sino al resto de usuarios que entren y la consulten

Comment: Ya... Pues, primero que nada había puesto el "no hay datos registrados" en el HTML y el if/else no lo afectaba entonces lo pasé a un echo del if, luego cambie todo el HTML de las tablas pasándolo a un echo con las variables sin el <?php ?> en cada una de ellas, no soy muy bueno explicándome, pero espero se entienda

Comment: por favor edita y agrega todo lo que me comentas pero en tu respuesta

Comment: Ya lo acabo de hacer, espero sea entendible

Comment: Gracias por responder el problema que tenía ya lo solucione pero me dejaste con una incógnita como es recomendable unir código html con php o viceversa; así como yo puse más arriba o como @Patrick lo hace con echos? O eso ya depende de uno? Gracias

Comment: Paolo, eso ya depende de uno... Pero hacerlo con echos hace que tu página sea más dinamica

Comment: Depende un poco de lo que quieras hacer @paolo . Yo, por ejemplo, en lo que estoy desarrollando lo devuelvo como html puro en un variable, y al llamar a la plantillahtml.php, que es donde está todo, carga el html pintandolo en la web, pero con las combinaciones que le de en las funciones. No es recomendable hacerlo con echo si es algo un tanto enrevesado. Lo bueno es hacer un listado de funciones e ir llamando en función del código que necesites. Pero claro, esto es mi punto de vista, no necesariamente ha de ser así siempre.